# Javascript Text Variations Search

Tags: javascript

Is there an easy way besides using the OR (||) expression to look for all variations of PO Box using javascript?

```
if((Address).indexOf("PO BOX") > -1 || if((Address).indexOf("PO Box") > -1
```

The address field is being pulled from a pre-populated database column. I need to disable an option if the address has any variation of PO Box in the address column.

I reviewed the [Mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) but didnt find anything I could use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just convert Address to lowercase?

```
const needle = "Po BOx"

if(Address.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) > -1)
```

OR

```
if(Address.toLowerCase().includes(needle.toLowerCase()))
```

Comment: The PO Box variations entered in the table is all kinds you can think of. Its painful but I can pull a list of all variations. I have been using the OR and that list is getting long!

Comment: Lets say Address is `PO box`. It would get converted to `po box`. In this case you just need to look for `po box` in order to find it.

Comment: OK. Let me try that. In that case, I may just need two entries lowercase(P O Box) and lowercase(PO Box). Thank you!

Comment: Exactly! It's common pattern.

Answer (score 4):

The best is probably this:

```
const found = Address.toLowerCase().includes("po box");
```

Comment: totally agree. indexOf is obsolete for such things.

Answer (score 2):

Convert address to lower case and search for the value

```
if((Address.toLowerCase()).indexOf("po box") > -1
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can use any of following ways:**

1. `if( Address.test(/po box/gi) )`.
2. `if( Address.toLowerCase().includes("po box"))`
3. `if( Address.toLowerCase().indexOf("po box")) > -1`

P.S:- Personally i think 1st method is more clean and fast.

Comment: 1st method though a) needlessly searches globally to know of the presence of the substring once b) has the overhead of a regex engine c) harder to substitute other search strings in the source (cos its a regex literal, but not using any real features of a regex)

Answer (score 0):

This would be an appropriate use case for a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). 
Below are a few tests - you can see the `test` function returns a boolean value indicating whether your search string was found.

The `i` after the second `/` means that the the regex search will be **case insensitive**.

```js
const regex = /po box/i;

const s1 = "Send to PO Box 1000";
const s2 = "Send to PO box 1000";
const s3 = "Send to po Box 1000";
const s4 = "Send to po box 1000";
const s5 = "Send somewhere else!";

console.log(regex.test(s1));
console.log(regex.test(s2));
console.log(regex.test(s3));
console.log(regex.test(s4));
console.log(regex.test(s5));
```